# How do you remove a dot deb package (Upgraded from Squeeze to Wheezy)

Tags: php, debian, dotdeb

I have run sudo apt-get remove php5 and it says php5 is removed but I can still load phpinfo() from one of the web pages and all the websites still load. I have also restarted the server.

I don't know how to remove the dotdeb version of php, I just want to wheezy packaged version.

[image]

Comment: Have you reloaded Apache since removing the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make sure to include --purge. In my apt-get remove command.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing aren't installed files but not purged. When you `remove` you only will uninstall non-configuration files. Those files always stays unless you use `--purge` (in case you will be executing another command like `autoremove`) or `purge package`. This configuration files are most of time safe to keep around unless you don't want the cruft and confusion it can cause.

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using dpkg-query -l.
dpkg is cool as well. You can purge with dpkg and sometimes resolve dependency problems with it. 
dpkg -P php*

Check man dpkg.